# How to add exclusion/negation to a generic rewrite rule in IIS 8?

Tags: regex, iis, iis-8, regex-negation

I am using a regex in a rewrite rule (on IIS 8) to deny access to all files and folders starting with a dot (.)
This way, these Urls cannot be accessed :

- https://example.com/.forbidden_file
- https://example.com/.forbidden_folder/somefile.txt

  ```
  <rule name="Deny access to files and folders starting with . or /." patternSyntax="ECMAScript" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(^\.|\/\.)" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
  </rule>
  ```

Today I would like to add an exclusion, in order to allow access to a specific file named ".specific_allowed_file", and a specific folder named ".specific_allowed_folder", like this :

- https://example.com/.specific_allowed_file
- https://example.com/.specific_allowed_folder/somefile.txt

I have managed to achieve it by adding two conditions, like this :

```
    <rule name="Deny access to files and folders starting with . or /." patternSyntax="ECMAScript" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(^\.|\/\.)" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="(.*)(\.specific_allowed_file$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="(.*)(\.specific_allowed_folder)(.*)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
```

Do you know if this is a reliable implementation, or if I should rather use another method, like modifying my matching regex ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Instead of creating a complex regular expression to exclude certain paths, I suggest you add extra rules, https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f

Comment: @LexLi : That is an interesting way of doing it, but it has the flaw of breaking the flow of the rewrite rules. My rule preventing files and folders starting with a DOT comes before a lot of other rewrite rules. Using *stopProcessing=”true”* is a very bad idea in my case, as the next rewrite rules would be ignored, what I do not desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a very good one since it allows users add conditions using readable and clear code. One thing should be noted: `pattern="(.*)(\.specific_allowed_folder)(.*)"` will also allow a `.specific_allowed_folder_WITH_MORE_TEXT_HERE` as well. You may fix it to match only folders by adding `/` into the first and third groups and making them optional by placing a `?` quantifier right after the groups:

```
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^(.*/)?(\.specific_allowed_folder)(/.*)?$" negate="true" />
```

If you want a single regex to do the whole job, use a regex with a negative lookahead:

```
<match url="(^|/)\.(?!(specific_allowed_file|specific_allowed_folder)(/|$))" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/quqJEG/1).

**Details**

- `(^|/)` - start of string or `/`
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?!(specific_allowed_file|specific_allowed_folder)(/|$))` - that is not immediately followed with `specific_allowed_file` or (`|`) `specific_allowed_folder` substrings that are followed with `/` or end of string (`$`).

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew, Frankly, your answer is concise though very useful. PERFECT ! I have refined my regex following your recommendations by adding slashes / before and after "specific_allowed_folder" to ensure that only the exact "specific_allowed_folder" can be targetted. And I share your point : using <conditions> help better understanding what is going on. Finally, I have always been eager to know how to use negative lookaheads, without really knowing how to. I will preciously keep your example behind me for some cases where <conditions> are not available, for example in my source code.